# How to format date field in Django admin while allowing Null values

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I didn't like how Django Admin displays DateTimeField values which is like "Sept. 4, 2012, 6 a.m.".  I changed this to YYYY-MM-DD by adding this function in a class in admin.py:

```
def d_ordered(self, obj):
    return obj.date_ordered.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
d_ordered.short_description = 'Date Ordered'
d_ordered.admin_order_field = 'date_ordered'
```

which works and allows the field header sort.

HOWEVER, if ANY date records are NULL then I get the error **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime'**.

How do I fix this error while still allowing NULL date values and header sorting?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are performing a method on a None value. So you first have to check if the field is not None:

```
if obj.date_ordered is None:
    return ''
```

Comment: If my response answered your question, please accept it as the answer.